# IIS using Microsoft.Web.Administration and commiting changes

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

*goal*
Change IIS bindings and swap virtual directories on a per request basis. A simple application  will open, replace and commit, using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration`. Following is a simplified flow:

*code*

```
ServerManager = New ServerManager()
config = ServerManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
SiteList = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites")
SitesCollection = SiteList.GetCollection()
_site = SitesCollection.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.GetAttributeValue("name").ToString() = "XXX")
_bindings = _site.GetCollection("bindings")
_bind As ConfigurationElement = _bindings.CreateElement("binding")
_bind("protocol") = "http"
_bind("bindingInformation") = String.Format("*:80:{0}", "www.zzz.yyy")
_bindings.Add(_bind)
ServerManager.CommitChanges()
```

*problem*
This code run on an administrator authenticated web page, and  before the call, the thread is impersonated to make sure the privileges are in place. I'm allowed to read the .config but not to write! I also confirmed that, before any call, the thread is running as Administrator. I also tried using a LocalService pool but again, no luck.

*the error*

```
Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file due to insufficient permissions
hresult: 0x80070005
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: Thread impersonation is useless. LocalService is not local administrator. You have to run in a pool with LocalSystem as identity.

Comment: Tried all of the above, including using  a LocalSystem identity pool.

Answer (score 0):

After some checking and experiment I find out that the way to make it work was

- Do not use authentication on the application.
- Do not use impersonation.
- LocalService does not work.
- Run it on a pool with enough privileges (administrator)

Looks like using impersonation breaks it again.

This is NOT the setting I wanted but I think I can survive and move the app to this unsecure pool,  work the changes and the move it back to a generic ApplicationPoolIdentity.